# how to implement video streaming in black berry?

Tags: blackberry

I have implemented one project in which I want to implemet video streaming functionality
Say for example:User can see youtube video in bleck berry.
I want to implement for blackberry bold 9700(with 4.7 OS ).
Is it possible?If yes then how it possible?Can you give me some idea about my query.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

just port mp4 demuxer, AAC and AVC decoder.

Comment: can you tell me some dtails.thax in advance

Comment: there are enough details. Now you need just to find these components available on the net or develop them by yourself.